# XAdES creation with manual signature entry

Tags: digital-signature, signature, pkcs#11, xades

I am trying to create a digitally signed XML document using the signature from my ID card.

I have two parts of the program. The first one is getting the certificates and signature of the file from the ID.
For that I am using python PKCS11 library with something like this:

```py
with open("input.xml", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

lib = lib('path/to/pkcs11/lib.dylib')
token = lib.get_token('name of token')

with token.open(PIN) as session:
    certificate = None

    for obj in session.get_objects({Attribute.CLASS: ObjectClass.CERTIFICATE}):
        certificate = obj
        der_bytes = certificate[Attribute.VALUE]

    with open('certificate.der', "wb") as f:
        f.write(der_bytes)

    # calculate SHA256 of data
    digest = session.digest(data, mechanism=Mechanism.SHA256)

    for obj in session.get_objects({Attribute.CLASS: ObjectClass.PRIVATE_KEY}):
        private_key = obj

    signature = private_key.sign(digest, mechanism=Mechanism.RSA_PKCS)

    with open('signature', "wb") as f:
        f.write(signature)
```

That generates the `certificate.der` and `signature` files and is working properly (at least I think)

For the XML generation part I am using Europe's DSS library in Java like this:

```java
DSSDocument toSignDocument = new FileDocument("input.xml");

// Preparing parameters for the XAdES signature
XAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new XAdESSignatureParameters();

// We choose the level of the signature (-B, -T, -LT, -LTA).     
parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.XAdES_BASELINE_B);

// We choose the type of the signature packaging (ENVELOPED, ENVELOPING, DETACHED).
parameters.setSignaturePackaging(SignaturePackaging.ENVELOPED);

// We set the digest algorithm to use with the signature algorithm. You must use the
// same parameter when you invoke the method sign on the token. The default value is SHA256 parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA256);

CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("certificate.der");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

// We set the signing certificate
parameters.setSigningCertificate(new CertificateToken(cert));

// Create common certificate verifier
CommonCertificateVerifier commonCertificateVerifier = new CommonCertificateVerifier();

// Create XAdES service for signature
XAdESService service = new XAdESService(commonCertificateVerifier);

// Get the SignedInfo XML segment that need to be signed.
ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, parameters);

File file = new File("signature");
SignatureValue signatureValue = new SignatureValue(SignatureAlgorithm.RSA_SHA256, Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

// We invoke the service to sign the document with the signature value obtained in
// the previous step.
DSSDocument signedDocument = service.signDocument(toSignDocument, parameters, signatureValue);

File signedFile = new File("output.xml");
signedFile.createNewFile();
signedDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(signedFile, false));
```

That creates XAdES file, but when I try to validate the signature (e.g. using [this](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation)) it fails saying the signature is not intact.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `dataToSign` variable at all for signature value creation.

What you should do is by using the private key corresponding to the created certificate to actually sign the digested `dataToSign`. I.e., instead of:

```
File file = new File("signature");
SignatureValue signatureValue = new SignatureValue(SignatureAlgorithm.RSA_SHA256, Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

you should do something like this (using your example above):

```
# calculate SHA256 of data
digest = session.digest(dataToSign, mechanism=Mechanism.SHA256)

for obj in session.get_objects({Attribute.CLASS: ObjectClass.PRIVATE_KEY}):
    private_key = obj

signatureValue = private_key.sign(digest, mechanism=Mechanism.RSA_PKCS)
```

Please pay attention, that you shall sign not the original document, but the `dataToSign`, as it contains the reference to the original document (its digest), but also signed parameters, required to ensure compliance to AdES format.

I hope this will help you.

Best regards,
Aleksandr.